# Apache CouchDb and mobile capabilities

Tags: couchdb

If i have a couchdb server to enter information from a mobile platform and that might go offline. Do i have to install another instance of the database on the mobile platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want seamless offline capabilities then CouchDB is the way to go. You can install a compatible CouchDB version on devices and cloud servers, and use Couch's awesome replication powers for world domination, while your users remain blissfully unaware of their telco's poor stability.

Comment: ils there a simple way toi install ait on the phone?